# Converting Map Value Type with QueryDSL and Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, querydsl

Documents inside my MongoDB Database have two primary attributes - Headers and Payloads. My POJO saves the headers as a Map with key String and value String. However, there is a Timestamp field in my map of headers that is read in as a String by QueryDSL due to the Map restriction I've placed.

How can I use QueryDSL to compare a Timestamp value (Long) saved as a String?

Should I have created my header to map key type **String** to value type **Object**? If that's the case, how can I perform operations such as .startsWith or .contains when the path returned is now a SimplePath and not a Path that allows more complex comparisons(like StringPath or DateTimePath)?

My document object:

```
@Document
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String id; 
    public Map<String, String> headers;
    public Object payload;
```

The method creating a predicate that takes in a headers Map object and compares it to queryDSL's qEvent headers Map object.

```
    public Predicate createQuery(Map<String, String> headers, Long startTime, Long endTime) {
            QEvent qEvent = QEvent.event;
            BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
            if (headers != null) {
                if (isValid(headers.get("stringID")))
                    builder.and(qEvent.headers.get("stringID").containsIgnoreCase(headers.get("stringID")));
                if (isValid(headers.get("type"))) 
builder.and(qEvent.headers.get("type").containsIgnoreCase(headers.get("type")));
....
//additional String comparisons on fields inside headers
//this is where the StringPath created by queryDSL suffices for everything except for Long/Timestamp values

return builder.getValue(); 
}
```

I've looked into creating my own dynamic path for the timestamp field but was stuck after the following:

```
    PathBuilder<Event> entityPath = new PathBuilder<Event>(Event.class, "entity"); 
    PathBuilder<Timestamp> timestamp = entityPath.getMap("headers", String.class, Timestamp.class).get("timestamp");
```

Is the above even a correct start? Does using Mongo as my underlying database mean that the first line above should actually be the following:

```
PathBuilder<Event> documentPath = new PathBuilder<Event>(Event.class, "document");
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case it wasn't obvious in my question, I was overthinking it.

The solution to this problem was to simply create my own "Headers" object - a nested class inside the original POJO.

The Event class should be as follows:

```
@Document
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String Id; 
    public Headers headers;
    public Object payload;
```

Inside my Event class is a static Headers object with fields relevant to what I need - one of which is "timestamp".

```
public static class Headers {

        //some more fields inside my Headers object
        //can be found here

        @Field
        public Long timestamp; 

        @Field
        public Long jms_timestamp; 

        @Field
        public String originator; 

        @Field
        public String eventName;
```

The method that then queries for a Predicate remains the same and can compare longs/Strings/any other types accordingly.